# How to make not to generate struct tag `json:"omitempty"`

Tags: go, ent

I am using **Go Ent** for ORM in my Go server.

The problem is, whenever I generate codes by custom schema, it makes all the fields with `omitempty` tag.

For example, this is my `ent/schema/user.go`.

```
type User struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the Account.
func (User) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.String("name").
            MaxLen(63).
            Unique(),
        field.Int32("money"),
    }
}
```

After I run the command `go generate ./ent`, it makes `ent/user.go`.

```
type User struct {
    config `json:"-"`
    // ID of the ent.
    ID int `json:"id,omitempty"`
    // Name holds the value of the "name" field.
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    // Money holds the value of the "money" field.
    Money int32 `json:"money,omitempty"`
}
```

I am using this `*ent.User` type as HTTP response body, but `Money` field has `omitempty` tag, so there is no `money` json field if the user has no money.

I know that replacing `omitempty` tag can be done with the following code, but I wanna replace this tag for all the fields I define at once.

```
type User struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the Account.
func (User) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.String("name").
            MaxLen(63).
            Unique(),
        field.Int32("money").
            StructTag("json:\"money\""),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the fields and modify the descriptor:

```
func (User) Fields() []ent.Field {
    fields := []ent.Field{
        field.String("name").
            MaxLen(63).
            Unique(),
        field.Int32("money"),
    }
    for _, f := range fields {
        f.Descriptor().Tag = `json:"` + f.Descriptor().Name + `"`
    }
    return f
}
```

Or

```
func TrimOmitEmptyTag(fields []ent.Field) {
    for _, f := range fields {
        if f.Descriptor().Tag == "" {
            f.Descriptor().Tag = `json:"` + f.Descriptor().Name + `"`
        }
    }
}

func (User) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return TrimOmitEmptyTag([]ent.Field{
        field.String("name").
            MaxLen(63).
            Unique(),
        field.Int32("money").
            StructTag("json:\"money\""),
    })
}
```